# How to approach simple recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, methods

I've been trying to understand recursion/recursivity in programming languages and I've chosen to work with python, since it's the language I understand the most. I've tried resolving the following problem -

Given three different lists of elements, find all the possible patterns that a certain person has followed during his shopping day.

**Lists**

```
purchases = [[money_spent, time0], [money_spent, time1], [money_spent, time3]]

time_between_shops = [[time_to_self, time_to_shop2, time_to_shop3, time_to_shop4],
                     [time_to_shop1, time_to_self, time_to_shop3, time_to_shop4],
                     [time_to_shop1, time_to_shop2, time_to_self, time_to_shop4],
                     [time_to_shop1, time_to_shop2, time_to_shop3, time_to_self]]

list_of_products = [["shop1", {"product1": price_of_product1, "product2": price_of_product2}],
                    ["shop2", {"product3": price_of_product3, "product4": price_of_product4, "product5": price_of_product5}],
                    ["shop3", {"product6": price_of_product6}],
                    ["shop4", {"product7": price_of_product7}]]
```

In those lists purchases are ordered by their time (earliest to latest purchase) and shops have the same indexes in the list_of_products as in time_between_shops. Time between shops can be the same, but the time it takes to go from shop A to shop B can be different from the time it takes to go from shop B to shop A. The given time is in minutes where 0 is 0:00 and 1439 is 23:59.

Given that information, I know how to approach this problem the regular way, however I need to use recursive methods to obtain all the possibilities. I've read up on recursive methods, so I know what they represent, and when I see one I can understand what it does and how it works, but when it comes to creating recursive methods on my own, I get lost since I always go back to regular methods.

So how should I approach this problem in order to resolve it using recursion instead of the regular methods?

Comment: What are the "*regular methods*" you are talking about?

Comment: By "regular methods" I mean there might be ways of resolving this by using a non-recursive algorithm, however I haven't thought in that direction because that's not how I'm supposed to solve the problem. There might as well be none, I haven't tried to go in that direction enough for me to say if any of them would work.

Comment: In its current state your problem does not seem exactly *solvable*. Do you have values for the travel times? Expected input and output? Or are we trying to calculate the number of possible iterations?

Comment: @Donkey Kong
I have fixed values of the time traveled between shops. All the values exist, I just tried to generalize the problem. Here is what I should give to the program
`time_between_shops = [[0,5],[7,0]]
purchases = [[28.79,[15,57]],[13,[16,4]]
list_of_products = [["shop1", {'Bananas':5, 'Candy':3, 'Books':7.95}],
 ["shop2", {'Keyboard':20, 'Gloves':5, 'Ring':3.79, 'Horse Toy':8.79, '5kg of rice':10.95}]]`

and the expected output is all the possibilities for the person's shopping route. Here, the shops at shop1 for 28,79 dollars and then goes to shop2 and spends 13 dollars.

Comment: I think that this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum
subset sum algorithm can help me out in finding all possible combinations of articles for the purchase in a single shop. What remains after that is finding all route possibilities.